# Basic xCode 4 build question

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, xcode4

This is a very basic, very silly question, but I have three build configurations, Release, Debug and Ad-Hoc.  But, when I choose Archive from the product menu, how does it know which configuration to use? Additionally, when I choose Run, how does it know?

I know it is dumb, but I am a newbie so I took a chance that any question was ok to ask!!  -:)

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Use the search young programmer. http://theruprect.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/ad-hoc-app-distribution-with-xcode-4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined in the new scheme feature of Xcode 4. If you go to "Edit Scheme.." you can set an configuration for each Build-Command (Test, Archive etc.).